# Adjust Line Spacing Java

Tags: java

Is there a way to adjust the spacing between new lines when outputting to the console through `System.out.println`? I'm attempting to print out a square with a basic nested for-loop, but I keep getting a rectangle despite having the right number of characters. This is because the spacing between the characters is different than the spacing between lines. Any ideas?

Comment: Your current code would probably help.

Comment: Depends entirely on what console/IDE you are using, and its font.

Comment: This question may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014454/how-can-i-change-line-height-line-spacing-in-eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

The standard output stream is just a stream of data; how that data is displayed is up to the application displaying it (e.g. a terminal or your IDE). You'll either have to settle for a rectangle, or find a different method of output than standard out.

Answer (score 0):

Without your current code, it's hard to say exactly whats going on.  My first thought is, make sure you're using a character that is as high as it is wide, e.g. `*`.

Second thought is (and again, I have no code to reference), see if you get the same result using one of the algorithms here: [Printing a Square with loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238155/printing-a-square-with-loops), perhaps there is an issue with the square-printing logic that you overlooked.